# What does "constituencies" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/constituency#constituency__17

> Kamens (1977) suggests that the major function of a college or university is to redefine novice students as graduates who possess special qualities or skills. The value of the status transformation is negotiated with important **constituencies** through constant references to the quality and rigor of educational programs. The significance of the conversion from novice to graduate is validated by structural characteristics, reputation of faculty, success of former students, or appearance of the institution.

Source: https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=iRArDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA286

Comment: This book seems full of educational *jargon*.   If you are not already very familiar with the specific meaning of terms like "constituencies" in this context, you will probably have a hard time reading this book, as you will likely not find the correct definition in the normal dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "constituency" can mean an "interest group". In this context it means "groups of people who are interested in the educational outcomes of students". Such groups would include "employers of graduates", "the government", "parents of students" and probably others.